# CSRF Protection in a Flask Framework that uses Dash

Tags: python, flask, csrf, plotly-dash

This question builds upon my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59448482/6924364) about dash integration.

## Question:

When CSRF is activated using the `flask_wtf` module, how do you also integrate Dash modules without blocking Dash posts due to a lack of csrf tokens?

## MWE:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render template
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from dash import Dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


app = Flask(__name__)

csrf = CSRFProtect(app)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'somethignrandom'

dapp = Dash(__name__, server=app, routes_pathname_prefix='/dash/')

dapp.layout = layoutfunction # this is left for your imagination

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def helloworld():
    return render_template('index.html') 

@app.route('/dash')
def dashing():
    dapp.layout = layoutfunction

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This returns a 404 error whenever `/dash` is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/308

## Solution

Add the following line to exempt dash from csrf token requirements:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render template
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from dash import Dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = Flask(__name__)

csrf = CSRFProtect(app)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'somethignrandom'

########## ADD THIS LINE

csrf._exempt_views.add('dash.dash.dispatch')

##########


dapp = Dash(__name__, server=app, routes_pathname_prefix='/dash/')

dapp.layout = layoutfunction # this is left for your imagination

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def helloworld():
    return render_template('index.html') 


@app.route('/dash')
def dashing():
    dapp.layout = layoutfunction

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## Comments

1. Whether or not this is an acceptable solution is up for debate. I am not sure if this opens Dash to injections.
2. I am not aware that there is a way to add csrf tokens to dash but if there is, I will update my answer.